# PNG background image not showing in IE 8< using html5?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the following html code:

```
<section class="first-content-top">
    <img src="images/img-diner.png" />
    <h1>Menu</h1>
</section>
<section class="first-content-middle">
         <article class="menu">
     </article>
</section>
<section class="first-content-bottom"></section>
```

With the following type of css:

```
.first-content-middle 
{
    background: url("images/bg-black.png") repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 37px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 595px;
}
```

But in IE8 i still can't see a background image, like i see in IE9 or firefox:

**Here's a picture of IE8:**

[image: Here's a picture of IE8]

**And here is a picture of firefox, how it should be:**

[image: And here is a picture of firefox, how it should be]

***I tried the follwing solutions:***

To prevent the problem i added the following html5shiv code to the head of the page:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

And in firebug i checked to make sure that the section element has the `display:block;` property set.

Edit: Adding the `height` css property to the section fixes the background problem. But the section height is variable. So how do i fix that?

Any suggestions?

Comment: can we check this on any testserver or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Note: here it's a test so OK whatever but when in production, html5shiv should be added if `IE lte 8` or `IE lt 9`, not on IE9 and 10 where it's useless.

Comment: I would love to help you resolve this, but really, I don't think I have enough information. Either a working example of the problem in a jsfiddle or more code is needed, as it could well be an interaction of code causing the issue. If you cannot post a fiddle of the issue, then can you post all the css for the three different `section` elements along with sample html/css of the `article` element? This may help to track down the solution.

Comment: It's showing fine for me in IE8 mode on Win 7, so either you fixed it, or it is specific to some other factors (operating system, etc.). I guess I won't be of any help.

Comment: @ScottS that's true on windows 7 putting IE9 in IE8 mode everything looks just fine. On windows xp IE8 it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your png background image needs to be at least 4x4px.

Comment: This link is broken - this seems to be a good solution: http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

Answer (score 1):

.first-content-middle 
    {
        background: url("images/bg-black.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
        margin: 0 0 0 37px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        width: 595px;
    }

remove transparent from background

Comment: i'm sorry it doesn't really say transparent. That's firebug code. I'll change my anwser to the right css source code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to your issue.  Generally IE9 and below doesn't like transparency, opacity.

[Surplus in ie7 and ie8 intead of being Transparent while using PNG transparent and opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951287/problem-with-png-transparent-opacity-on-ie7-and-ie8)

Comment: That code will only work on img elements and not background images. Which is exactly the problem. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 have native PNG support for alpha-transparencies, but it falls to pieces as soon as opacity comes into the picture. When setting any value for opacity, even 100% (ie. filter: alpha(opacity = 100)), IE fills in the alpha-transparency of the PNG with a pure black fill. This is sometimes refered to as a 'black halo'. The alpha filter can be removed at any time to remove the fill and restore the alpha transparency, but supporting both requires using more of IE's propriatary filters. All of the follow examples should be placed in a IE-targete

```
/* Normal CSS background using an PNG with an alpha transparency */
#demo {
background:url(ie8-logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: There is no css opacity. Thats already into the background image which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set section to display:block in your CSS

> With IE, even with the shiv, you need to declare the HTML 5 elements
>   as block elements. I use this line for Internet Explorer, but you can
>   modify it for the elements you need.
>
> ```
> header,nav,article,footer,section,aside,figure,figcaption{display:block}
> ```
>
> From the Modernizr Documentation: "you’ll also probably want to set
>   many of these elements to display:block;"

from [IE not styling HTML5 tags (with shiv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602758/ie-not-styling-html5-tags-with-shiv)

Comment: Still doenst work, sorry. Here's a link to the developer enviroment: http://dev.webrtb.com/zinn/cafe/