# Changing IE8 page elements using inline styles?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, inline-code

Since IE8 doesn't handle PNG 24 transparencies very well, I decided to nix the background image of my PNG's container div so that the background matches the background of my PNG.

Basically, I want to get rid of the background image for #myDiv in IE8 or earlier browsers.

In the header of my page I use:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>    <style>
#myDiv{margin-top:20px;}
#myDiv{background-image: none;}
</style> <![endif]-->
```

Changing the margin-top works fine (along with all other adjustments that I made for IE8).  Yet the background image still appears, no matter what I try!  Short of getting rid of it in my external style sheet, I can't seem to make it not appear.

In fact, when the page loads, it looks like the code initially gets rid of it, but it comes back.  I thought that inline styles always trump the external style sheet.  Am I wrong?

I checked my css @media stuff, and there's nothing in there that might bring it back.  I cleared my browser cache and refreshed.  Still there.

Anyone have any clue why #myDiv's  background image keeps coming back?

EDIT: I'm working in the header.php template of a wordpress site. (That's where I inserted the code above.)  So maybe the external style sheet does indeed trump inline styles in this case??  I don't see why it should, but could that be the answer?

Comment: As far as I am aware, IE8 is *supposed* to support alpha transparency with PNGs.  Does it need to be 24 bit?  You can have alpha transparency with an 8 bit PNG which I know *does* work in IE7:  http://www.sitepoint.com/png8-the-clear-winner/

Comment: Yes the selector that sets the background image is exactly the same id.  In fact, I removed the attribute from my external style sheet just to be sure that's where the background image was coming from.  Removing it from the external style sheet gets rid of the image, but not the code above.  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: @cimmanon: I have a bunch of 24 bit images in a slider I'm using, and they're colorful, so I don't want try to change them to 8-bit.  I thought it would be easy enough to just get rid of the background image in the surrounding div.

Comment: @Adrift: the margin-top part of it is new.  It's not in my external style sheet.  But that doesn't matter, because the background image stays whether I change the margin-top or not.

Comment: I even tried changing some other attribute of #myDiv just to see if it can be done. Sure enough, other attributes (e.g. display:none;) work, but "background-image:none:" works for a microsecond, then the background image comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a perfect solution, but would adding the background image as a media query work (as IE8 does not support media queries)?

```
@media (min-width: 1px) {#myDiv{background-image:url(/etc/etc/etc.png);}}
```

Comment: Thought that might work, but strangely enough, IE8 went right ahead and read the media query and set the background image. :^(

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also make sure your background image is at least 4px x 4px

Here is a related post:
[PNG background image not showing in IE 8< using html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197601/png-background-image-not-showing-in-ie-8-using-html5)